# ExportToHttpResponse gives : "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack."

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, httpresponse

On load of ASP.Net page, a report function is called.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalFunctions obj = new GlobalFunctions();
    obj.GetReport(Page PageName, string ReportName);
}
```

GetReport is defined as :

```
public void GetReport(Page PageName, string ReportName)
{
    ReportClass rpt = new ReportClass();
    rpt = GetReportFromDLL(ReportName);   //No error here
    rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, ReportName); 
}
```

Error :

> "Response" is not accessible through the Class.

I have tried using "HttpContext.Current.Response" in place of "Response"

```
rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,HttpContext.Current.Response, true, ReportName);
```

But I get this error:

> "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a
>   native frame is on top of the call stack."

Please help!

Comment: have you tried using a reference instead of an instance? I think Page has issues with copying.

Comment: I suspect passing `Response` as parameter is not acceptable due to coding style, but consider to try it anyway...

Comment: @Camron - What should i pass as reference? Please clarify

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - The code works if GetReport function is in the Default.aspx page. Currently, since the GetReport function resides in GlobalFunctions.cs, "Response" is not accessible.

Comment: sorry for not clarifying, I'm new to giving advice. I think the page variable. If I remember correctly the Page instance is created outside of the scope of the implementation itself, and in fact outside of the instance that is the server response. I think that the Page instance is created by the thread that spawns the IIS responses, and is protected from copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite an effort, I found that **ExportToHttpReponse always threw an error** "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack." **if the entire code block is NOT in a Try-Catch Block.**

Here is the solution to avoid this error:

```
public void GetReport(Page PageName, string ReportName)
{
    try
    {
        ReportClass rpt = new ReportClass();
        rpt = GetReportFromDLL(ReportName);   //No error here
        rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, ReportName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //do nothing
    } 
}
```

This just removes the error and the report gets printed on the HttpResponse.

Comment: is this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you can't pass response to a function... Try following

```
  public void GetReport(HttpResponse response, string ReportName)...
```

And call as:

```
   obj.GetReport(Response, "some report name");
```

Comment: Thanks Alexie, but i still get the same error --
    {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Comment: @IshGoel, you do understand that the error you posted has nothing to do with code, don't you? Searching for error text is important skill for a developer, but rare - here is explanation for the error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439654/unable-to-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-is-optimized-or-a-native-frame-is. Now most likely your code have bug(s) and that is why you end up debugging it, but it is unlikely related to code you are trying to fix.